# Dplyr/Lubridate: How to summarise overlapping intervals after grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I would like to group agreements and then compare how much their periods overlap (or are apart).

My dataframe may look like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tribble(
~ShipTo,    ~Code,  ~Start, ~End,
"xxxx", "AAA11",    2018-01-01, 2018-03-01,
"yyyy", "BBB23",    2018-02-01, 2018-05-11,
"yyyy", "BBB23",    2018-03-01, 2018-06-11,
"cccc", "AAA11",    2018-01-06, 2018-03-12,
"yyyy", "CCC04",    2018-01-16, 2018-03-31,
"xxxx", "DDD",    2018-01-21,   2018-03-25
)
```

I would like to mutate a column to create lubridate periods and evaluate them after grouping by ShipTo and Code. What I tried was:

```
dft3<-dft %>% filter(concat1 %in% to_filter2)  %>%
  arrange(ShipTo,Code)%>% 
  group_by(ShipTo,Code)%>%
  mutate(period=interval(Start,End), 
         nextperiod=interval(lead(Start),lead(End)),
         interv=day(as.period(intersect(period, nextperiod), "days"))) %>%
  group_by(ShipTo,Code)%>%
  summarise(count=n(),
    intervmax=max(interv),
    intervmin=min(interv))
```

If I remove the line group_by(ShipTo,Code)%>% the intervals are created correctly and also the lead intervals are correctly calculated from the next line. But when I naively use group_by, the intervals are not calculated correctly.

I suspect that perhaps my database should be split into many tables by groups and then, after the operation of creating and comparing intervals it should be glued back together.

Is there a succinct way to do it? Or perhaps there is a simpler way I have not yet learned? Thank you in advance for the hint in the right direction.

EDIT: The desired output should be a column with value of overlaps of intervals in days (or distances between intervals if no overlap). Grouping destroys the calculation. I would like to have these values calculated within groups (not accross them).

EDIT2: I trying to solve the problem by splitting dataframe into a list of dataframes and then combining it, but I am not sure of a syntax. It does not quite work, produces tables with one column, a help I was given on other portal (perhaps it can ilustrate the issue). The idea is to split a database, create new columns and combine the tables to a single table.

```
    fnOverlaps <- function(x) {

      mutate(x,okres=interval(Start,End),
             nastokres=interval(lead(Start),lead(End)), 
             interv=day(as.period(intersect(okres, nastokres), "days"))) 
    }

dft3<-dft3 %>% 
  split(list(.$ShipTo, .$Code), drop = TRUE)  %>%   
  map_df(fnOverlaps) %>% 
  flatten_dfr()
```

The result (for one group) that I expect would look like this.

```
tribble(
~ShipTo,    ~Code,  ~interv,    
"yyyy", "BBB23",    70        #say there is a 70 days overlap
"yyyy", "BBB23",    NA        #there is no next row to compare

)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? and what does the desired output look like?

Comment: The desired output should be a column with value of overlaps of intervals in days (or distances between intervals if no overlap). Grouping destroys the calculation. I would like to have these values calculated within groups (not accross them).

Comment: In your sample data, each group has only a single row. There is no "next" line within the group (for most groups) against which to compare. So, either: your example data doesn't show the full problem (in which case, update the data), or you are not stating your intention correctly (e.g., that you want to compare to the next row regardless of group, but want to summarise by the group. Either issue would be helped by showing the result you want to get from your sample data (and fixing your example code to omit columns that don't exist in the sample data -- notably the `filter` step)

Comment: @MarkPeterson I would like to compare rows within groups, eg: for rows 
"yyyy", "BBB23",    2018-02-01, 2018-05-11, and
"yyyy", "BBB23",    2018-03-01, 2018-06-11, I have an overlap of several days. I would like to have an "interv" column with the value of that overlap in days. It can be so, that the valid result will be only for one record in the group of only two records, and for the next record in the group it will be NA since there is no next record, I have no problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is being caused by trying to combine vectors with the class "Interval." Specifically, they appear to be getting converted to numeric and losing their inherent information.

I think the only viable solution is to `split` the data.frame, run the analysis on each component separately with `lapply`, then bring them back together with `bind_rows`. The number of groups with only one entry present an issue as `max` and `min` return `-Inf` and `Inf` when the argument is empty after removing NAs. But, that is easy enough to correct for.

This code should work. Note that I am using `group_by` to ensure the ShipTo/Code columns are kept, though you could do that in other ways.

```
dft %>%
  split(paste(.$ShipTo, "XXX", .$Code)) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    x %>%
      arrange(ShipTo,Code) %>% 
      mutate(period=interval(Start,End)
             , nextperiod=interval(lead(Start),lead(End))
             , interv=day(as.period(intersect(period, nextperiod), "days"))
      ) %>%
      group_by(ShipTo,Code)%>%
      summarise(count=n(),
                intervmax=max(interv, na.rm = TRUE),
                intervmin=min(interv, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      ungroup()
  }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(intervmax = ifelse(is.infinite(intervmax)
                            , NA, intervmax)
         , intervmin = ifelse(is.infinite(intervmin)
                              , NA, intervmin))
```

Returns

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  ShipTo Code  count intervmax intervmin
  <chr>  <chr> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 cccc   AAA11     1      NA        NA  
2 xxxx   AAA11     1      NA        NA  
3 xxxx   DDD       1      NA        NA  
4 yyyy   BBB23     2      71.0      71.0
5 yyyy   CCC04     1      NA        NA
```

Comment: Thank you. I also got a similar help with map_db on slack, but not that elegant, ie  intersect is calculated correctly but the intervals indeed convert to numeric. There is even the warning they will be... but should not they stay periods? This example will also be good for learning! Again thanks. Would it be appropriate to put it in here just for a record?

Comment: @JacekKotowski -- Glad this worked. I don't know enough about the internals of how periods are stored to understand what is causing the issue. They seem to work with `c()` fine outside of `group_by`/`mutate`, so it may have to do with the method(s) being used to re-vectorize. But, I don't even know enough to know where to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting it just for the record. I received an answer from Jake Knaupp on slack r4ds group with the modern map_df() syntax, it calculates overlap of periods but ***it converts periods to numeric. And there is a bunch of warnings it will do that.***

```
myFun <- function(x) {

  mutate(x,period=interval(Start,End),
       nextperiod=interval(lead(Start),lead(End)), 
       interv=day(as.period(intersect(period, nextperiod), "days"))) 
  }

df %>% 
  split(list(.$ShipTo, .$Code), drop = TRUE) %>% 
  map_df(myFun)
```